# Merge tags 'translation' and 'localization'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

We have the tags [translation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) (x6) and [localization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) (x65). Should the two be merged, with `translation` becoming a synonym to `localization`? The current 6 "translation questions" deal with topics very close to "localization", which would speak *for* a merge. A possible argument against could be the term "translation" being applied to content as well (as e.g. with "Google Translate").

Being unsure, I seek your opinions. Clearly, we have two options:

- Yes: Merge the two and synonymize. Optionally update the tag wiki of "localization" to make it clear.
- No: Translation should be applied to content. In this case:

  - re-tag questions closer related to "localization"
  - create a tag wiki for "translation" making clear what this tag is about

What do you think? Maybe I even missed a third option?

**EDIT:** I just noticed a third related tag: [languages](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) (x76)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for short-circuiting your vote, but this seemed pretty clear-cut to me since most of the translation questions were in fact localization questions.  I've merged and synonymized.

I think [languages](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) is alright to stay separate since it seems like a proper subset of localization, but I'm open to other options.

Comment: No need to be sorry (and thanks for your action!) -- I just took into consideration that others might be as confused as me. Good that someone (you) has a clear view on this :) I was tending to the same direction, or I wouldn't have asked. So what's left is me checking the tag wikis of the two remaining tags whether they might need some clearification. Will do so on this weekend (currently I'm a little in a rush). Thanks again!

Comment: @Izzy No problem, thanks again for all your work on our tags lately!

Comment: Also no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we should merge the two: [localization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) should be the merge target, `translation` should become its synonym.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two should stay separate:

- [localization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) shall remain for the "technical issue" of having apps and their dialogs, hints, etc. using the local language, which will of course include "helping to translate an app" (*How can I make Android to always use my language, including all its apps?* being a possible example question). The tag wiki might need to be updated to make this clear.
- [translation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) should be used for content related questions/issues, such as e.g. problems with translation apps (Google Translate & Co) as well as questions like *How can I automatically translate web pages in the stock browser?*

  - questions tagged 'translation' but rather referring to different topics should be re-tagged
  - a tag wiki should be created for the `translation` tag to make its use clear